# Separating values of an Array to select boxes

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of different sizes and I want to separate each row of sizes out into its own dropdown list.

I am having trouble separating each size to its own select option.

```
var arraySize = [
                 "S, M, L", 
                 "XS, S, M, L"
                ];

$.each(arraySize, function(index, element) {
    $('.sizeContainer').append($('<option>', {text: element}));
});


// Desired output
<select>
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option value="XS">XS</option>
  <option value="S">S</option>
  <option value="M">M</option>
  <option value="L">L</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jdzax0rg/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a `<select>` within each iteration, then split the "element" by comma to get the different sizes and add them each of the sizes to the earlier drop down list.

One solution would be:

```js
$('#testButton').click(function() {

  var arraySize = ["S, M, L", "XS, S, M, L"];

  $.each(arraySize, function(index, element) {
  
    // Create the drop down list and keep a reference
    var ddl = $("<select>").appendTo(".sizeContainer");

    // Split the sizes by comma
    var sizes = element.split(",");
    
    // Loop through each size adding it to the ddl
    for (var i in sizes) {
      ddl.append($('<option>', {
        text: sizes[i],
        value: sizes[i]
      }));
    }
  });

  return false;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="testButton" href="#">Test</a>
<form method="POST" class="sizeContainer">
</form>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdzax0rg/14/

Answer (score 0):

Use following. See it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jdzax0rg/19/):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a id="testButton" href="#">Test</a>
  <form method="POST">
    <select class="sizeContainer">

    </select>
  </form>

<!-- JS  -->
$('#testButton').click(function(){

    var arraySize = ["S, M, L", "XS, S, M, L"];

    $.each(arraySize, function(index, element1) {
            var res = element1.split(",");
        $.each(res, function(index, element) {
        $('.sizeContainer').append($('<option>', {text: element}));
        });
    });

  });
```